# ADO.net ASP.net How to Fill datatable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I am new to this....How do I correctly fill this datatable ? The editor does not like this code, it gives me squiggles beneath the last occurrence of *conn* and *Fill*

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class WebForm4
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim connstring As String
    connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Z:\CompanyData.mdb"

    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    conn = New OleDbConnection(connstring)

    conn.Open()

    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "select * from Company"

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strSql, conn)

    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    da = New SqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = cmd

    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt, "Company")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `OleDb` to use an `MS-Access` database. You should use `OleDb` classes for everything. You create an `SqlCommand` and a `SqlDataAdapter`, these classes work for `Sql Server` but not with `OleDb`.

```
Dim connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Z:\CompanyData.mdb"
Dim strSql = "select * from Company"

Using conn = New OleDbConnection(connstring)
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(strSql, conn)
    conn.Open()

    Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter
       da.SelectCommand = cmd
       Dim dt = New DataTable
       da.Fill(dt, "Company")
   End Using
End Using
```

I have changed a bit your code to show how to use the [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). This statement is very important to keep your code clean because it closes and disposes every disposable object declared in the `using` line.

Comment: @brian Thx for your kind help!